# custom options price calculation

Tags: magento, custom-attributes

How does custom options price calculation work for a fixed and percent price?

I want to change percent calculation functionality from base price to total price.
Currently it's calculating price from base price.
How to change this from base price to total price?

For example:

- base price = $10
- custom option1 = $10
- custom option2 = 10%
- default Magento calculation:

  - Total price = Base price + selected custom option1 + selected custom option.
  - Total price = $10+$10+ 10% of $10(baseprice) = $21.

But we need this Total price after selecting the custom option:

- Total price = $10+$10 = $20.
- Total price after select custom option2

  - Total price = $20 + (10% of Total price)
  - Total price = $20 + (10% of $20).
  - Total price = $20 + $2 = $22.

I need to calculate the percentage from the total price, not from the base price. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

This is done in

`Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Price::_applyOptionsPrice`

If this applies only to special products, you might want to create an own product type with a customer price handler.

Comment: but its only take effect in product page. if i click 'Add to Cart' then it will go to shopping cart page and show default price calculation values.not customized price calculation value